# `conda` gives "No such file or Directory" although I added PATH in my .bash_profile

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, homebrew-cask

My Jupyter notebook and Conda was breaking down so I decided to remove everything and install it again.

I installed anaconda using `brew cask install anaconda`
Afterward, I added `export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` in my `.bash_profile`
(Everything from [this instruction](https://medium.com/ayuth/install-anaconda-on-macos-with-homebrew-c94437d63a37))

However, when I type `conda --version` it says
`-bash: /Users/leonard/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory`

1. **Why does this happen and how can I fix it?**
2. I just want to get my Jupyter notebook, R, and Python working. Is it possible to use these without using Anaconda? I've been having so many troubles.

Comment: what do you get when you enter 'echo $PATH' into your terminal ?  
are you able to change directories into /Users/leonard/anaconda3/bin/  and see conda listed in this directory ?

Comment: @NiallJG I am able to change to the directory. But guess what, I re-started iTerm and it magically works now. Thanks for your help tho.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Close that terminal and restart,It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

***With the Apple M1 chip, I did the following to get into the problem.***

1. Installed miniconda at custom path `/Users/myApple/opt/miniconda`
2. Then for tensorflow I installed miniforge at `/Users/myApple/miniconda`
3. Which gave me the following issue, when I entered "conda env list" [Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527131/conda-environment-has-no-name-visible-in-conda-env-list-how-do-i-activate-it-a)
4. Then I reinstalled miniforge in the same dir as miniconda

And finally, I got the error conda gives `No such file or Directory`.

**Solution:**

- Already mentioned in the question itself, to add the newly installed miniforge path to .bash_profile
- removed older installation of miniforge
- `Close that terminal and restart,It worked for me`

And all is working now
Thank you all

Comment: Conda is not designed to have multiple **base** installs (e.g., Anaconda, Miniconda, Miniforge). They are all equipotent as environment managers, and are essentially just variations on configuration settings and initial packages.